# É possivel manipular os numeros de um randint?

Tags: python-3.x

Por exemplo, eu queria que os números gerados por um `randint` fossem `350`, `400`, `450` e `500`. Teria como fazer isso?

Comment: Não ficou claro. Você quer algo que sorteie aleatoriamente valores definidos? Não fez muito sentido.

Comment: kkkk realmente ficou bugado, é tipo assim se eu colocoar pra ele dar um a = randint(350, 500) ele vai sortear do 350 ate o 500 tipo 350 351 352 eu so queria esses valores 300 350 400 ...

Comment: ficou um pouco mais claro agora?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi, o que você quer fazer é gerar números dentro de um `range` e definir o *passo*. Nesse caso pode usar o `random.randrange()`, que recebe por parâmetro o ínicio, fim, e o passo. Algo como:

```
import random
valor = random.randrange(350,501,50)
```

Por favor, seja mais claro nas próximas perguntas, isso ajuda a te ajudar :)

Referência: [documentação random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#functions-for-integers)

Comment: valeu consegui fazer oq queria

Answer (score 2):

Para fazer o que você quer, você poderia usar `random.sample`, por exemplo:

```
random.sample([350, 400, 450, 500], 1)
```

Onde o primeiro parâmetro são os possíveis valores e o segundo parâmetro quantos valores você quer de retorno.

Retornará:

> [400]

Fonte: https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/random.html

Comment: valeu consegui fazer oq queria